# What is the purpose of chaining constructors?

Tags: java

I am a novice and could someone please help me to know the type of scenarios where constructor chaining useful and what is the purpose of "this()" in the program? Here is the code.

```
public class Constructor_chaining {
Constructor_chaining(){
    System.out.println("Default constructor...");
}
Constructor_chaining(int i){
    this();
    System.out.println("Single parameterized constructor...");
}
Constructor_chaining(int i,int j){
    this(j);
    System.out.println("Double parameterized constructr...");
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Constructor_chaining obj=new Constructor_chaining(10,20);
}}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: Avoiding code repetition usually

Comment: In this case, `this()` is not that helpful. If you have a super class and if you don't have a parameterized constructor then the case you mentioned is helpful

Comment: Topic starter too lazy to read docs

Answer (score 4):

It can be used to avoid code repetition. Let's put an example:

```
public class Test
{
    int a;
    int b;

    public Test(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Test(int a, int b)
    {
        this(a);
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test t1 = new Test(1);
        Test t2 = new Test(1,2);
        System.out.println(t1.a + " " + t1.b);
        System.out.println(t2.a + " " + t2.b);
    }
}
```

Here the `two-parameter constructor` calls the `one-parameter constructor` to initialize the field `a`, so you don't have to repeat all the code in the `one-parameter constructor` inside the `two-parameter constructor`. Of course with this little example, it looks like it is unuseful, but imagine that you have a lot of fields you want to initialize. It will be very useful.

Regarding `this()` question: According to [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, **`this`** is a reference to the current object...
>
> From within a constructor, you can also use the **`this`** keyword to call another constructor in the same class. Doing so is called an *explicit constructor invocation*.

So `this()` is used to call the constructor (without parameters in this case) of the class `Constructor_chaining`.

Answer (score 2):

It has the purpose of reducing code duplication. Without constructor chaining you often would have to repeat whatever is in one constructor in another.

On typical case is the implementation of default arguments, where one constructor A calls another B and providing fixed values for one or more arguments, while passing the others right through.